# How to open and run a userform?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform on an Excel file called "userform":

```
Private Sub add1_Change()
End Sub

Private Sub add2_Change()
End Sub

Private Sub Calc_Click()
Result.Value = Val(add1.Value) + Val(add2.Value)
End Sub
```

This userform takes the value from the user and adds them together and shows the result in a textbox.

I want to create a new macro in another workbook named "input". The macro in this workbook should open the userform workbook, enter values in the textbox add1 and add2, then run the userform calculate button.

What I've tried thus far:

- Set `add1.value` to extract a value from say, cell A1, and similarly for `add2.value`.
- Then I created a macro on the input workbook to change the values in cells A1 and A2.

The problem from here is I don't know how to open the userform and click calculate.

Ideally, I would like a macro which opens the userform, enters the data and hits calculate then closes the userform - Rather than editing the userform itself.

Comment: Why use the userform at all for that? The point of a form is to get input from the user. If you aren't doing that, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: having something like this `Public Sub getUF(a): Set a = UserForm1: End Sub` in the wb with the userform, allows to catch that object directly... simply run `getUF MyUFVariable` and then use `MyUFVariable` exactly the same way like you would with the userform...

Comment: @Rory I agree with your point, but I have a much bigger useform than the one shown and it would be easier to do it this way rather than breakdown the userform from scratch. It's just what I'm required to do for now.

Comment: @DirkReichel could you elaborate a bit more on this? I've added what you said, but say I wanted to change the value on the add1 textbox how would I call it? Right now, I have this:

'Sub userform()
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
a = Cells(1, 2)
b = Cells(2, 2)
Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\userform.xlsm")

Application.Run "userform.xlsm!Calc"

End Sub' the calc macro just opens up the userform, I don't know how to actually "input" data or hit calculate

Comment: @james1395 you want to get Input from a `Worksheet`, do a calculation and then place it somewhere? What else does your `UserForm` do to not want to change now to a pure VBA code option instead of unneeded `UserForm`'s

Comment: @DragonSamu Yes, I want to get input from the workbook input, create a macro which enters these inputs into the userform and hits calculate. I know it's a long winded way and goes against the use of a userform but this is why I'm asking here.

Comment: @james1395 ok, but still to properly understand what is the function of the `UserForm`. If you just want a calculation we can provide guidance to how to do that

Comment: @DragonSamu the function in this example would be simply add numbers in the textbox add1 and add2, and output them onto another textbox called Result. So the code I posted in the comments (apologies for the format, I am not sure how to format in comments) opens the userform workbook, and it opens the userform "UserForm1" by running the macro "Calc" i.e. Application.Run "userform.xlsm!Calc where Calc just has code to show the userform. I now want to fill the textbox add1 and add2 and somehow activate the calculate button which adds those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the 2 values in the `UserForm` in this way(its slightly different then you try to do it now):

You use your current code to open the `UserForm`:

```
Sub userform()
    Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\userform.xlsm")
    Application.Run "userform.xlsm!Calc"
End Sub
```

As shown above you don't assign any values this will happen in your `userform.xlsm Workbook`

Below is the code you put into the sub `Initialize` of your `UserForm`:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks("input.xlsx")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Input")

    Dim i as Integer
    Dim k as Integer

    UserForm.add1.Value = ws.Range("A2").Value
    UserForm.add2.Value = ws.Range("B2").value
    UserForm.calc.Value = val(UserForm.add1.Value) + val(UserForm.add2.Value)

End Sub
```

As shown above `calc` is changed to a `Textbox`, therefor you don't need to click a button its directly done when the UserForm is loaded.

You could also use a `Label` instead of a `Textbox`.

the code would then change to:

```
UserForm.calc.Caption = Str( val(UserForm.add1.Value) + val(UserForm.add2.Value) )
```

Comment: Thanks, this works - but I really want to avoid changing the original userform, i.e. that should stay the exact same, but only edit the input workbook - do you know if this is possible at all?

Comment: @james1395 The problem with that is you need to simulate a `Click event` which isn't pretty and will be prone to failures because your making VBA act like a button is pushed. Would it really be that problematic to change a `Button`?

Comment: Calling the subprocedure calculate public works. Thanks anyway

Comment: @james1395 ah, you didn't put that code inside the click button then it works yea :)

Answer (score 0):

> @DirkReichel could you elaborate a bit more on this? I've added what you said, but say I wanted to change the value on the add1 textbox how would I call it? Right now, I have this: 'Sub userform() Dim a As Integer Dim b As Integer a = Cells(1, 2) b = Cells(2, 2) Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\userform.xlsm") Application.Run "userform.xlsm!Calc" End Sub' the calc macro just opens up the userform, I don't know how to actually "input" data or hit calculate

*The answer:*

I created 2 WB and just this simple code worked for me ... however: you may need to change the settings of the trust center.

Book1 Module: (the WB with `Userform1` holding `TextBox1` and `CommandButton1`)

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getUF()
  Set getUF = UserForm1
End Function
```

Book2 Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public ExtUF As Variant

Sub the_UF()
  Workbooks.Open "Book1.xlsm"
  Set ExtUF = Application.Run("Book1.xlsm!getUF") 'get the Form

  Debug.Print ExtUF.TextBox1.Value  'check old value
  ExtUF.TextBox1.Value = "dada"     'change it
  Debug.Print ExtUF.TextBox1.Value  'check for new value

  ExtUF.CommandButton1.Value = True 'hit the button
  ExtUF.Show                        'show the form
   Stop 'to check the userform
  ExtUF.Hide                        'hide it again
End Sub
```

Now just run `the_UF` and check for functionality. If everything does work, adopt it to your code the way you need it.

If you have any questions, just ask ;)